# How to login a Django account from an iOS App?

Tags: django, authentication

In my App I need to communicate with my Django website. Some resources require authentication so I need user login.

But this does not happen in a browser or a web view. I need to use Object-C to issue a login request and handle the response - basically to store the session ID I guess.

On the web server side, how should I do this in Django? To have a stand-alone view for that and return JSON maybe? How can I get the newly generated session ID though?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't get the session ID.  I believe logging in a user is more geared toward a web interface.  I would create an API that serves the resources you need in your app.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer  Authentication would probably be best suited for a private/public key pair or some other similar popular api authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make any changes to your authentication system, save for maybe making sure the login form is usable on the smaller screen. Cookies work the same on iOS as they do on the web. You can display a modal UIWebView with your login form. After the user logs in, presumably you are setting a session cookie. If you make a subsequent request to the domain the cookie matches, the cookie should be sent along. You want to look into the HTTP 'Accept' header field, which specifies the content type the client expects to receive. In your controller (view?), you'll want to check the 'Accept' header, and return the appropriate content type, probably 'application/json' (or a custom type for your API).